# [HTTP response code]Does one REST API only respond one successful code?

Tags: rest

Background:
I'm using Java with Spring boot framework. I have one REST API which input parameter is a int flag, when the flag is 0 then the API will give the response '200' and when the flag is 1 then the response is '204'

[edit]
Now, I can give the response of '200'. But I don't know how to return '200' and '204' by using condition for the REST API.

Question:
Can a REST API return different successful code? If it can, how should I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: You have to tell us what language and framework you are using, we can not magically guess. Hint: Whatever language and framework you are using, google how to set the response code

Comment: @sinanspd Thanks for your comments, I just update my question. I have google this question, but most of the answer is how to return only '200' or only '204'.

Comment: You can not return multiple codes in one request. Put an `if` statement in your code and figure out which response code to return based on the flag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Boot allows you to customize the HTTP response by editing/creating @RestControllers:

```
@RestController
public class DoStuffController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/do-stuff", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void doStuff(@RequestParam int flag, HttpServletResponse response) {
       if(flag == 0){
          response.setStatus(HttpStatus.OK);
       } else {
          response.setStatus(HttpStatus.SC_NO_CONTENT);
       }
    }
}
```

The above is untested - but should react to a POST /do-stuff?flag=[0|1] by returning eithet HTTP 200 or 204.